# Check if product is variation / has parent?

Tags: magento2

This should be easy, but I'm having trouble figuring out / searching out a solution.

What code could I use to check if a product is a variation, or has a parent? I want to execute code if a product is either a configurable product or a simple product without a parent, ignoring all simple products that aren't variations. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableType
) {
    $this->configurableType = $configurableType;
}
```

Now you can use following way for getting parent id:

```
$parentIds = $this->configurableType->getParentIdsByChild($productId);

$parentId = array_shift($parentIds);
```

Here **$parentId** will return if a simple product is a variation of config product